# Using azure mobile backend not hosted in azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, backend, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a Windows 8.1 store app that uses a Azure Backend.  I created the backend in Visual Studio and chose to host it on Gear Host instead of Azure because of cost.  This was done by deselecting the "Host in Cloud" option.

How can I add the backend service to my app? 
I know with Azure I add a connected service, but I can't do this with a different hosting service.

Comment: Specifically related to the cost issue... [You can host up to 10 Mobile Services for free](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/). This is great for testing, but would not suffice for a popular production app. For that, I recommend you apply to [Microsoft's BizSpark program for startups](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/). This includes $150/mo. in Azure credits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just host the Azure Mobile Service template in another hosting provider. This template has many dependencies on the Azure Mobile Services SDK and Azure features, such as Tables.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables;
```

This template is based on an ASP.NET Web API template so you might be able to create your own custom mobile backend.

Comment: If that is true, then why does Visual Studio have this option? [Screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cFdxjUop7LdlRQUFhWNUdvVkk/view?usp=sharing) I also get the message that the mobile service is up and running from the [status page](http://modernposbackend.gear.host/)